# How to convert multi-valued truth table to if-conditions or expressions

Tags: python, algorithm, karnaugh-map

I've got a table like this:

```
Location    Weather Temperature Time of Day Activity
Indoors Sunny   Hot Morning Reading
Indoors Sunny   Hot Evening Watching TV
Indoors Sunny   Cool    Morning Reading
Indoors Sunny   Cool    Evening Watching TV
Indoors Rainy   Hot Morning Reading
Indoors Rainy   Hot Evening Watching TV
Indoors Rainy   Cool    Morning Reading
Indoors Rainy   Cool    Evening Watching TV
Outdoors    Sunny   Hot Morning Gardening
Outdoors    Sunny   Hot Evening Barbecue
Outdoors    Sunny   Cool    Morning Playing Sports
Outdoors    Sunny   Cool    Evening Barbecue
Outdoors    Rainy   Hot Morning Shopping
Outdoors    Rainy   Hot Evening Barbecue
Outdoors    Rainy   Cool    Morning Shopping
Outdoors    Rainy   Cool    Evening Barbecue
None    Sunny   Hot Morning Reading
None    Sunny   Hot Evening Barbecue
None    Sunny   Cool    Morning Reading
None    Sunny   Cool    Evening Shopping
None    Rainy   Hot Morning Reading
None    Rainy   Hot Evening Barbecue
None    Rainy   Cool    Morning Shopping
None    Rainy   Cool    Evening Shopping
```

In this table, each input, such as "Location," "Weather," "Temperature," and "Time of Day," can only have specific values. For example, "Location" can only be one of: Indoors, Outdoors, or None. The table includes rows for all possible combinations of these input values.

I'm aware of how to create functions for boolean truth tables, but I'm looking for guidance on handling non-boolean truth tables like this one. I'd like to create a Python function based on this table that takes these specific input conditions and produces the corresponding "Activity" as output. The function should be efficient, without redundant code or conditions. Is there a straightforward way, an algorithm, or a tool that can help me turn this table into a Python function? I'm looking for some guidance to create it myself.

Comment: What's stopping you from just storing this table as a dictionary and simply looking up this table?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm

Comment: @AlpacaMax Valid solution, but it may require storing many values when the output can be determined with a few inputs. Trivially, if the first column is the sole variable affecting the output, other columns can be omitted. If there's non-random logic, this simplifies the expression to just a few checks. However, I'd avoid this for readability.

Comment: If you want to do the conversion by hand, the first step is to (stable) sort the list by `Activity`. Then do Karnaugh elimination, e.g. `Indoors Sunny Hot Evening` and `Indoors Sunny Cool Evening` both map to the same activity, so they can be combined as `Indoors Sunny X Evening` where X means "don't care".

Comment: @Saif Another option is to store this table in a database and just query the database. This avoids storing the table in memory and allows you to update the truth table in the future.